# c# .NET Screen Scraping with Inputs

Tags: c#, .net, regex, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping

I want to screen scrape the following website using C# Compact Framework because I don't think there is a publicly available api for it (I could be wrong). It has several controls on it that I want to set values for before submitting the page and moving on to the next form full of controls. How can I go about doing this. Other posts don't really talk about how to set input values.

```
http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/tickets/refunds/tuberefund/
```

I understand how to get the page HTML using HttpWebRequest or WebClient but not how to edit the page and post it back.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you might be better off if you used a browser plugin and/or a wireshark trace to trace the HTTP requests being sent by the browser when you do your scenario manually, and then replicate that network session exactly using code.

Parsing controls and coming up with POSt requests to simulate forms submit is also doable, but is a lot more work.

Also you might look to see if that website exposes any REST or Webservice apis that give you the capability you need to solve your problem.

Comment: I've done more research and am pretty sure there is no api for it. I 'm looking into whether I can just pass in the parameters to the url and submit the form that way. That would be great. If that does not work I don't know what to do next.